# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then can $N$ be of the form $q^k \cdot (\sigma(q^k)/2) \cdot {n}$?

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

A number $M$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(M)=2M$.  For example, $6$ and $28$ are perfect since
$$\sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 2\cdot{6}$$
and
$$\sigma(28) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 + 28 = 2\cdot{28}.$$

It is currently unknown if there are infinitely many *even perfect numbers*.  It is also an open problem whether any *odd perfect numbers* exist.  It is widely believed that there are no odd perfect numbers.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $N$, if one exists, must necessarily have the so-called *Eulerian* form
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

**QUESTION**

Here is my question:

> Can the odd perfect number $N$ be of the form
> $$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n}?$$

I would certainly appreciate it if anybody could point me to papers/articles/publications in the literature where this particular inquiry is covered.

**CONTEXT**

[Slowak (1999)](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128884/MathSlov_49-1999-3_3.pdf) proved that the odd perfect number $N$ must be of the form
$$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{d},$$
where $d > 1$.

[Dris (2017)](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) showed further that $d$ must have the form
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$.

---

**Edit (01/31/2022 - 10:42 PM Manila time)** Please check my proof attempt for $\sigma(n^2) \neq q^k n$ [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4370431/28816).

Comment: What is a difference between he claim in your question an the claim from  cited Slowak’s result? Is it required that $(q,n)=1$, whereas not necessarily $(d,n)=?$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @AlexRavsky.  Slowak does not necessarily claim that $d=n$.  Yes, it is necessarily true that $\gcd(q,n)=1$, while it is also necessarily true that
$$\gcd(d,n) > 1$$
since $\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \mid n^2$ and
$$\sigma(q^k) < \frac{2n^2}{3}.$$
But if I may just ask, why are you considering $\gcd(d,n)$?

Comment: Opps, $(d,n)=?$ was a misprint, sorry. There should be $\operatorname{gcd}(d,q)=1$ instead.

Comment: I meant $$\sigma(q^k) \leq \frac{2n^2}{3}$$ in my last inequality.  Yes, $\gcd(d,q)=1$ follows readily from $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  The divisibility constraint $\gcd(q,n)=1$ necessarily holds since prime powers are deficient.