# Is it true that $\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} > \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form?

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Preamble:  This post is an attempt to resolve the problem in [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738458).

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

A number $M$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(M)=2M$.  For example, $6$ and $28$ are perfect since
$$\sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 2\cdot{6}$$
and
$$\sigma(28) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 + 28 = 2\cdot{28}.$$

It is currently unknown if there are infinitely many *even perfect numbers*.  It is also an open problem whether any *odd perfect numbers* exist.  It is widely believed that there are no odd perfect numbers.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $N$, if one exists, must necessarily have the so-called *Eulerian* form
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

**UNDERLYING PROBLEM**

Here is the problem that I am considering:

> Can the odd perfect number $N$ be of the form
> $$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n}?$$

**CONTEXT**

[Slowak (1999)](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128884/MathSlov_49-1999-3_3.pdf) proved that the odd perfect number $N$ must be of the form
$$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{d},$$
where $d > 1$.

[Dris (2017)](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) showed further that $d$ must have the form
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$, and $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the [aliquot sum](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Dris and San Diego [(Theorem 5.6, page 22)](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-3/8-24/) proved that
$$D(n^2) > \frac{q+1}{2}.$$

Since it is **not true** that
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} \leq D(n^2) \leq \frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2},$$
**can we then say that**
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} > \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}?$$

If so, this would imply that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} > \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$$
which would mean that
$$n > \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

**In particular**, we have that
$$\frac{2n}{\sigma(q^k)} > 1$$
which implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} > n > \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

*This appears to prove that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \neq n$.*

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Does this proof hold water?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

Comment: FYI, one has $\dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} > \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\iff \sigma(q^k)\lt 2n$.

Comment: Agreed, @mathlove!  Please write out your last comment into a full answer so that I can upvote then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long to comment* :

One has
$$\dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} > \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\iff \sigma(q^k)\lt 2n$$
since
$$\begin{align}\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} \gt \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}
&\iff \sigma(q^k)s(q^k)-2D(n^2)\lt 0
\\\\&\iff \sigma(q^k)(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)-2(2n^2-\sigma(n^2))\lt 0
\\\\&\iff \sigma(q^k)(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)-2\bigg(2n^2-\frac{2q^kn^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)\lt 0
\\\\&\iff \sigma(q^k)(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)-\frac{4n^2(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)}{\sigma(q^k)}\lt 0
\\\\&\iff (\sigma(q^k)-q^k)\bigg(\sigma(q^k)-\frac{4n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)\lt 0
\\\\&\iff (\sigma(q^k)-q^k)\cdot \frac{(\sigma(q^k)+2n)(\sigma(q^k)-2n)}{\sigma(q^k)}\lt 0
\\\\&\iff \underbrace{\frac{(\sigma(q^k)-q^k)(\sigma(q^k)+2n)}{\sigma(q^k)}}_{\text{positive}}(\sigma(q^k)-2n)\lt 0
\\\\&\iff \sigma(q^k)\lt 2n\end{align}$$