# Follow-up to MSE question 3738458

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

This is a follow-up inquiry to this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738458).

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

A number $M$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(M)=2M$.  For example, $6$ and $28$ are perfect since
$$\sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 2\cdot{6}$$
and
$$\sigma(28) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 + 28 = 2\cdot{28}.$$

It is currently unknown if there are infinitely many *even perfect numbers*.  It is also an open problem whether any *odd perfect numbers* exist.  It is widely believed that there are no odd perfect numbers.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $N$, if one exists, must necessarily have the so-called *Eulerian* form
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Here are my initial inquiries:

---

**INITIAL QUESTION #1**

> If the odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ is of the form
> $$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n},$$
> can $\sigma(q^k)/2$ be a square?

**ATTEMPT #1 TO ANSWER MY INITIAL QUESTION #1**

Suppose that the odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ is of the form
$$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n}.$$
Evidently, $\sigma(q^k)/2 = n$.  Assume to the contrary that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is a square.  This implies (by a result of *Broughan, Kevin A.; Delbourgo, Daniel; Zhou, Qizhi*, [**Improving the Chen and Chen result for odd perfect numbers**](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.Abstract.html), Integers 13, Paper A39, 8 p. (2013). [ZBL1284.11009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1284.11009).) that $k=1$.  This contradicts Patrick A. Brown's result from [2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) that $q < n$, which together with the (trivial) estimate $2n = \sigma(q^k) < 2q^k$, implies that $k > 1$.

**ATTEMPT #2 TO ANSWER MY INITIAL QUESTION #1**

If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then [MSE user FredH](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82711) showed unconditionally that $n^2 - q^k$ is not a square.

Suppose to the contrary that $N = q^k n^2$ is of the form
$$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n},$$
where $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is a square.  From ATTEMPT #1 to INITIAL QUESTION #1, we again have that $k=1$.  It follows that we have $N = q((q+1)/2)^2$ must be an odd perfect number.

We now compute
$$n^2 - q^k = n^2 - q = ((q+1)/2)^2 - q = ((q-1)/2)^2,$$
which contradicts FredH's result.

---

We therefore conclude that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **not a square**.

---

**INITIAL QUESTION #2**

> If the odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ is of the form
> $$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n},$$
> can $\sigma(q^k)/2$ be squarefree?

**MY ATTEMPT TO ANSWER INITIAL QUESTION #2**

As before, under the conditions of the problem being considered, the equation $\sigma(q^k)/2 = n$ must hold.  Suppose to the contrary that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree.  This contradicts the fact that $n$ must contain a square factor. (*Steuerwald, Rudolf*, Verschärfung einer notwendigen Bedingung für die Existenz einer ungeraden vollkommenen Zahl, Sitzungsber. Bayer. Akad. Wiss., Math.-Naturwiss. Abt. 1937, 69-72 (No. 2) (1937). [ZBL0018.20301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0018.20301).)

---

We therefore conclude that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **not squarefree**.

---

**FINAL QUESTION**

> It follows that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is the product of a square and a squarefree number (both greater than $1$), if $N = \frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{n}$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Can you then obtain an expression for $\sigma(q^k)/2$, apart from the trivial equation
> $$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(n^2)/q^k} = \frac{n^2}{n} = n?$$